# How do I call an ASP link from VB code-behind instead of user clicking link?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a link here that works perfect for calling the postback close that I need to happen:

```
<a href="javascript:parent.__doPostBack('Close','')"><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Close Me"></asp:Label></a>
```

However, I would like to be able to call the ***javascript:parent.__doPostBack('Close','')*** method from the code-behind file rather than the user clicking the link. I.e., when I have completed my tasks in the application code, call parent.doPostBack as my last function call, which closes the window in question.

Any ideas how to call this client-side javascript method from the server side?

Comment: this postback actually call a code behind function, just call it after the end of your complete task, what you have miss understand here ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to all the code on this page. I am adding this code as a "custom object" into an application were working with. As such, the entire page I'm writing is displayed within an iFrame on the site.

Comment: The link works exactly how I want, but I dont want the user to click it. I want it to happen at the end of my application code.

Comment: register a script on start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for how to generate script to link to event handlers on the server (page). See these methods of `this.Page.ClientScript`:

```
GetCallbackEventReference
GetPostBackClientHyperlink
GetPostBackEventReference
GetWebResourceUrl
```

Also, explore other methods of the page's `ClientScript` property. There are some interesting ones beginning with "Register".